# Photoshop: With 3D Mesh, How to get rid of suddenly appeared gray cube?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't know how to express clearly about my problem. When I create new 3d mesh from layer postcard and rotate/move/roll the object at the beginning, everything works fine as expected. But suddenly after I click somewhere, there will be a gray cube with three axis (red/blue/green) comes out. After this, I can not really transform the 3d mesh correctly anymore. How to get rid of this gray cube?

PS1: Sometimes, double click the empty space will turn it off. Sometimes, double click does nothing. Double click many times in many different places may turn it off randomly. I can continue to my work now. Not sure why, but it works.

PS2: Adding the screenshot:

### The expected UI:

[image]

### The un-expected UI:

[image]

So far, I can use multiple double clicks to turn off the unexpected UI randomly.

Comment: CAn you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1397819/edit) to post a screen cap of what you're talking about?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry that I was lazy to upload screen caps after I can solve it by some random double clicks. Now, please check the question again, I have added two screenshots, one for expected UI and another one is unexpected UI. Thanks.

Comment: That is part of the interface to manipulate the object in 3D. See any good tutorial on using 3D in Photoshop, like [this one](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-create-3d-postcard-adobe-photoshop.cfm) for how to use it